# npm no responde en linux

Tags: nodejs, linux, npm, raspberry-pi, raspbian

últimamente estuve programando en un raspberry pi 4, y por algunas cuestiones tube que reinstalar el sistema, luego de hacer esto volví a instalar nodejs y npm:

```
sudo apt-get install node
sudo apt-get install nodejs
sudo apt-get install npm
```

Luego de esto actualice los paquetes con: sudo apt-get update

Por ultimo cree una carpeta e intente instalar express pero no optube ninguna respuesta por parte de la consola, ni al instalar ni al consultar la versión de npm:

```
$npm -v
npm init --y
npm install express
sudo npm install express
```

*NO optube ninguna respuesta al ejecutar esto comandos*, me parece muy raro ya que anteriormente había estado usando npm y nodejs.

*aclaro que estoy usando raspbian*

Comment: ¿Por qué colocás `$` antes de cada comando? ¿O se te escaparon al copiar los comandos en la pregunta?

Answer (score 1):

actualmente solucione mi problema. Lo hice de la siguiente manera:

1. Removí por completo node, nodejs y npm.
2. Descargue el binario para ARM v7 del sitio oficial de nodejs
3. Seguí la documentación de nodejs para la instalación del binario: https://github.com/nodejs/help/wiki/Installation
4. Luego de seguir **TODOS** los pasos, ejecute los comandos de prueba:

> ```
> node -v
> npm version
> ```

Con esto ultimo ya obtuve resultados y pude instalar express y jestjs.